# How do I set up a queue on the Flask server

Tags: python, flask

I wrote a simple server in Flask, and it receives an audio file, id and file name as input and should run a program that transcribes the audio file into text.

But when several requests arrive on the server, my PC freezes due to heavy load. It turns out that the server launches my transcription program for each file (from a new request).

Maybe someone knows how to set up a queue to process files.

On my server, several files can arrive at once in one request and then they are correctly queued, and if several requests arrive, the PC immediately hangs.

The server is installed on Windows 10.

The server code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/api/process_audio', methods=['POST'])
def process_audio():
     try:
         start_time = time.time()

         audio_file = request.files['audio']
         audio_id = request.form['audio_id']
         audio_name = request.form['audio_name']

         # Save audio
         audio_path = os.path.join('program_audio/audio', f'{audio_name}.mp3')
         audio_file.save(audio_path)
         
         # Start audio processing
         subprocess.run('starter.bat', shell=True)

         # We are waiting for the result
         text_file_path = os.path.join('program_audio/final_text', f'{audio_name}_final.txt')
         timeout = time.time() + 60
         while not os.path.exists(text_file_path):
             if time.time() > timeout:
                 return jsonify({'error': 'Timeout'}), 500
             time.sleep(1)

         # Forming a response
         end_time = time.time()
         elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

         response_data = {
             'audio_id': audio_id,
             'elapsed_time': elapsed_time
         }

         # Send the result
         response = send_file(text_file_path, as_attachment=True)

         # Start deleting the file after 5 minutes
         delete_thread = threading.Thread(target=delete_file, args=(text_file_path,))
         delete_thread.start()

         return response, response_data

     except Exception as e:
         return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, port=39588, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I tried to make a programmatic queue, when a file arrives on the server, it goes into the general queue, but this led to the fact that the server did not respond to anyone until it processed all the files from all users.

As an option I was thinking of using:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
```

But so far I have not been able to implement it into the server so that it works stably.

I don’t know, maybe Flask is not suitable for such tasks and I should use another library

Comment: Well, the flask operated on a sequential model by default. What you are doing is best fit for async task . Refer [flask async](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/async-await/).  In your case, the controller will not respond until it finishes the work i.e., get the *_final.txt file. With async await you can simply yield control while you wait for the processing to happen to cater to other requests.